# Program won't start when using OpenCV in C++ to stream video from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, video-streaming, device

right, I have a USB camera connected to the PC and I want to use OpenCV to stream images from it. Here is my code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    CvCapture* cameraCapture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
    cvNamedWindow("Camera");

    while(1)
    {
        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(cameraCapture);
        cvShowImage("Camera", frame);
        if((cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27)
            break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&cameraCapture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera");
}
```

The problem is that when I start the program I get this pop-up error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application". I have made sure I have included all the correct libraries, header files and ddl's so I'm really not sure whats wrong with it.

Any help to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding some error checking at cvCaptureFromCAM and cvQueryFrame. Don't always be so optimistic they do fail.

Comment: Debug your application and find out which line causes this error.

Comment: Try to capture from video, and if this works, then probably is a problem of the camera... compatibility...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to try this way of dealing with cameras, using the OpenCV 2.3.1.

```
VideoCapture _videoSource;
bool camera = 1;

if(camera)
{
   if(!_videoSource.open(0))                // Try to start camera. 0 = default camera
   {                                    
    cout << "Error opening camera" << endl; // here you control why the error happens
    exit(1);                // Exit if fail         
   }
}
else
{
   if(!_videoSource.open(Path+"video.avi")) 
   {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        exit(2);                        // Exit if fail
   }
}
_videoSource.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 1);

Mat frame;
namedWindow("Image");

while(1) 
{
  _videoSource >> frame; 
  imshow("output", frame);
  return 0;
}
```

If this fails, the you will know for sure that the problem is with your camera. Maybe the drivers. Good luck.